# Read a large file and output sections matching multiple parameters

Tags: perl, awk

I rarely have to deal with scripting, so I'm up against a lack of knowledge for this problem.

I have a file >500mb in text, which is nicely sectioned, but I know there are 5 to 10 "bad" sections inside.  The data within the sections can be evaluated pretty easily by a human, I don't know how to do it in a program.

I pick up a known good value in `#Field MyField` - however if that value did not appear in `#FIELD LOCATION`, something went wrong.

An example of two sections within the file looks like this.  The first is 'bad' and the second is 'good'.

```
#START Descriptor
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=FOO&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
#START Descriptor
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=BAR&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
```

1. Sections start and end logically, with `#START` and `#END`
2. If `#FIELD LOCATION` does not exist, go to next section
3. If `#FIELD MyField="BAR"` and `#FIELD LOCATION` does not contain `BAR`, print all lines from this section to a new file.
4. Note - Clarification of `#FIELD MyField="BAR"` - this is a check value I put in by grabbing other info about the data as this file is being built (in my case it is a language indicator, such as EN or DE. so it would literally be `#FIELD MyField="EN"`  Any other value in this field would be ignored, this isn't a record that matches my criteria.

I believe this can be done in Awk or Perl, I can do very simple one-liners but this is beyond my skills.

Comment: Are the sections separated by newlines, or are they one after another?

Comment: Does your "good section" want to have a double quote between "LOCATION=" and "http:" ?

Comment: So what precisely makes the bad section bad? `Value=FOO` in the URL vs. `BAR` in the `MyField`? (and is there supposed to be a quote before the `http` in the good section?)

Comment: Kevin - the "bad" is exactly that, I have a known good value in MyField, and if that value didn't show up in the Location string, something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like below. It's just a rough draft, but it will work with your sample data. Use the [flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to find the start and end of records. Use a hash to store the field values, and an array to store the record.

I am simply checking if the value is in the location string, you might wish to further narrow the check by making sure it is in the correct place, or the correct case.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @record;
my %f;
while(<DATA>) {
    if (/^#START / .. /^#END */) {
        if (/^#START /) {
            @record = (); # reset
            %f = ();
        }
        push @record, $_;
        if (/^#END */) { # check and print
            if ($f{'LOCATION'} !~ /$f{'MyField'}/) {
                print @record; 
            }
        } else {         # add fields to hash
            if (/^#FIELD (.+)/) {
                            # use split with limit of 2 fields
                my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $1, 2;
                next unless $val; # no empty values
                $val =~ s/^"|"$//g; # strip quotes
                $f{$key} = $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
#START Descriptor
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=FOO&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
#START Descriptor
#FIELD LOCATION=http://path.to/file/here&Value=BAR&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
```

Comment: This was nicely commented and useful to me as the questioner.  Its very cool that I have both a "short" answer and a "long" answer.  Thanks!  (I'm fiddling with these suggestions now!)

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = "#END\n" }' -e '/MyField="(.*?)"/; print if !/Value=$1/' <file >newfile
```

Sets the [Input Record Separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) to `"#END\n"` so perl reads the 'chunks' into `$_` one at a time, then captures the value in MyField and prints the whole chunk if `Value=$1` (that is, that capture after 'Value=') is *not* present.

You may of course make the regexes more specific if needed.

Comment: print $_ is not necessary, $_ is the default variable, print should suffice

Comment: `file >newfile` would work just as well as `<file >newfile`. Actually it works better as [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV) will get set to the input file-name.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small `gawk` one-liner for you -

```
gawk '
{
    if ($2!~/^#FIELD LOCATION/)
    {
        next;
    }
    else
    {
        split($2,ary,"=|&");
        split($4,ary1,"=|\"");
        if(ary[4]!=ary1[3])
            {
                print $0 > "badrec.file"
            }
    }
}' RS="#END\n" ORS="#END\n" FS="\n" file
```

#### Input File:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
#START Descriptor # Good Record
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=BAR&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
#START Descriptor # Bad Record
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=FOO&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
#START Descriptor # Good Record
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=BAR&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk '
{
    if ($2!~/^#FIELD LOCATION/)
    {
        next;
    }
    else
    {
        split($2,ary,"=|&");
        split($4,ary1,"=|\"");
        if(ary[4]!=ary1[3])
            {
                print $0 > "badrec.file"
            }
    }
}' RS="#END\n" ORS="#END\n" FS="\n" file

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat badrec.file 
#START Descriptor # Bad Record
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=FOO&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) to `#END\n` and read directly records:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$/ = "#END\n";

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /^#FIELD LOCATION/m;
    /^#FIELD MyField="(.*)"$/m;
    next if /^#FIELD LOCATION.*$1/m;
    print
}



__DATA__
#START Descriptor
#FIELD LOCATION="http://path.to/file/here&Value=FOO&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
#START Descriptor
#FIELD LOCATION=http://path.to/file/here&Value=BAR&OtherValue=BLAH"
#FIELD AnythingElse
#FIELD MyField="BAR"
#END
```

Comment: In the 2nd record, where MyField=BAR and Location includes BAR, that's an OK record, my operations succeeded.  The prior record, where BAR is not appearing in LOCATION was the error.  It tells me I had a problem parsing the file in that location.  I only want to read the segments that had a problem.